# Местоимения, ссылающиеся на «что‑то» и «это»

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, местоимения

Корректно ли ссылаться на местоимение «что‑то» при помощи местоимения «оно»?

> 1.1. Чтобы спрятать **что‑то**, нужно лишь сделать так, чтобы никто не интересовался тем местом, где **оно** спрятано.

Как‑то более грамотно звучит с местоимением «это»:

> 1.2. Чтобы спрятать **что‑то**, нужно лишь сделать так, чтобы никто не интересовался тем местом, где **это** спрятано.

Особенно криво звучит, когда местоимение «оно» находится в форме В. п. «его»:

> 1.3. Когда **что‑то** хорошо спрятано, **его** не так просто найти.

Тут явно лучше подходит местоимение «это»:

> 1.4. Когда **что‑то** хорошо спрятано, **это** не так просто найти.

И наконец, ссылка на «это» при помощи местоимения «оно»:

> 2.1. Да, всё **это** хранится в секретности, потому что, если бы люди узнали, как **оно** используется, они бы слегка расстроились.

Также ещё более странно звучит, если местоимение «оно» поставить в форму Р. п. «него»:

> 2.2. *Да, всё **это** хранится в секретности, потому что, если бы люди про **него** узнали, они бы слегка расстроились*.

Answer (score 1):

Указательное местоимение *это* и личное местоимение *оно* служат совершенно разным целям и придают фразам разные смыслы.

#### Оно

Личные местоимения заменяют собой объекты. Если взять приведенные вами фразы, то *оно* используется для указания на упомянутое ранее *что-то*. *Что-то* в данном случае является антецедентом для *оно*: первичным упоминанием объекта, на который мы в дальнейшем ссылаемся с помощью местоимения.

Да, в этих фразах объект уже выражен неопределенным местоимением, но в этом нет ничего особенного: *что-то* выполняет роль первого упоминания объекта, о котором ничего не известно. Тут могло быть любое другое имя существительное (собственное или нарицательное), но мы не знаем деталей, поэтому используем неопределенный объект. Функцией *оно* является указать на этот объект, чтобы не приходилось постоянно писать *что-то*. Иными словами:

*Чтобы спрятать **что‑то**, нужно лишь сделать так, чтобы никто не интересовался тем местом, где **оно** спрятано.*

эквивалентно

*Чтобы спрятать **что‑то**, нужно лишь сделать так, чтобы никто не интересовался тем местом, где **что-то** спрятано.*

И *что-то* может быть заменено на любой другой объект. Поскольку *что-то* ведет себя как средний род, мы используем соответствующее личное местоимение. Если бы объект был в другом роде, было бы необходимо согласовать *оно* с этим объектом.

#### Это

В свою очередь, указательное местоимение *это* имеет иную функцию: оно используется для выделения объекта из ряда ему подобных. Мы больше не делаем отсылку к исходному упомянутому объекту, а уже явно указываем на конкретный объект.

Если *оно* играет роль объекта (Что? **Оно**.), то *это* выполняет роль признака (Которое *что-то*? **Это** *что-то*).

Таким образом, *это* заменяет собой некоторую характеристику, по которой мы выделяем конкретный объект. Если принимать во внимание русский двухступенчатый дейксис, то можно сразу заметить, что мы говорим о ближайшем *чём-то*, нежели о далеком *чём-то*: иначе бы мы использовали указательное местоимение *то*.

Иными словами, будь у нас другая характеристика, её бы можно было вставить на место *это*. В ваших примерах очевидной характеристики быть не может (объект неопределенный), поэтому я проиллюстрирую вот такой фразой:

*Многие не жалуют **фисташковое мороженое**, но я люблю именно (какое?) **фисташковое**.*

эквивалентно

*Многие не жалуют **фисташковое мороженое**, но я люблю именно (какое?) **это**.*

Обратите внимание, что если использовать местоимение *оно*, то синтаксическая связь радикально меняется:

*Многие не жалуют **фисташковое мороженое**, но я люблю именно (что?) **его**.*

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ) В вашем примере "Если оно играет роль объекта, то это выполняет роль признака" опечатка: вместо «оно» должно быть "что‑то"? Ведь мы рассматриваем случай, когда ссылка идёт на местоимение «что‑то», а не «оно».

Comment: К сожалению, не увидел в вашем ответе информации по поводу предложений 1.3, 2.1 и 2.2. Если у вас есть мысли по поводу них, дополните свой ответ, пожалуйста.